# cannot find method useJUnitPlatform for test task in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to configure gradle to run JUnit 5 tests. however, when I try to add `useJUnitPlatform()` in my gradle file to enable JUnit 5 support as Directed here [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html) I am getting the error

```
Could not find method useJUnitPlatform() for arguments [] on task ':test' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.
```

Here is my Gradle File

```
    apply plugin: 'java'

group 'com.notif'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://packages.confluent.io/maven/'
    }
}

tasks.withType(Test) {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
        showStandardStreams true
    }
}


dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.21.0"
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:1.0.0-cp1'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.0.0-cp1'
    implementation 'org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.11.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.11.0'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-streams-avro-serde:4.1.0'
    implementation 'biz.paluch.logging:logstash-gelf:1.11.2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.9.6'
    implementation 'org.asynchttpclient:async-http-client:2.2.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jcl:2.11.1'
}
```

Any Idea why this is happening, am I missing any dependency

Comment: Which version of gradle are you running? The mentioned method was added in version 4.6

Comment: I am running gradle 4.8

Comment: Are you sure ? Maybe a version mixup, several versions of Gradle ?

Comment: If you are using intelliJ it is worth checking which gradle are you using for given project (can be wrapper, task, local). To do so go to Settings and search for gradle. Then navigate to Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Comment: That Indeed was the case, Thanks a Lot. can you post this as the answer so I can accept it, Might help others in the future

Comment: I cannot see useJUnitPlatform() in your gradle file, what change did you specifically make to solve this problem. The answer is just a check but not a solution. It will be great if you specify how you solved the issue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using IntelliJ it is worth checking which Gradle are you using for given project (can be wrapper, task, local). To do so go to Settings and search for Gradle. Then navigate to Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Comment: Which one should be used?

Comment: there is no single answer that fits all, but generally you want to use the same version to run intellij tasks as you are using with command line (ie gradle tasks) so I would recommend going with wrapper. But on the other hand if you work with multiple projects and each have different Gradle version and you would want to save disk space / time required to download each version via network, you can install locally newest gradle and tell IntelliJ to use that.

Answer (score 14):

Here is how I fixed it. 
I had this test task in my `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events "started", "skipped", "passed", "failed"
        showStandardStreams true
    }
}
```

And I had these dependencies (You might want to refresh gradle so it takes them into account):

```
dependencies {
  testCompile('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.0')
  testRuntime('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.0')
  testRuntime('org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.4.0')
}
```

Then I used the gradle wrapper (I was using gradle **4.8**) so it stays stable from one computer to another:

```sh
./gradlew clean build test
```